# Android lollipop api does not show up

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've been trying to update my app to the android lollipop. But the api does not show up in the sdk manager below. Is the lollipop api released yet? or am I doing something wrong?

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should appear after you update `Tools` -> `Android SDK Tools`. Are you on Rev. 23.0.5?

[image]

Comment: Ok. thanks. got it now. I had to install updates and restart the SDK manger then it showed up